# Objective-C: How to play a video from the selection of a cell in the UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to be able for the user to play a video in the `MPMoviePlayerConntroller` by selecting the video by tapping a cell in my `uitableview`so i have this code to list file's into each cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];


    return cell;
}
```

This code works successfully but now i need to check what the user has selected so i have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSURL * movieURL = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  
    [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
    [player play];
}
```

But this code has a problem with the line `NSURL * movieURL = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` keeps crashing the simulator.

and i am probably being stupid but i cannot figure out how to fix this.

**Edit**

The problem is that `filePathsArray` is only returning the name and extension of the video file so for example it will only display `testvideo.mp4` when i should be getting the full path to that file. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the error shown on console, when it crashes ?

Comment: Is filePathsArray array contains any path object? Have you checked with NSLog inside didSelectedRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said that you are getting the file name only; this is because of the lines :

```
 filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
```

`cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];`

If you want to have full path you should do like:

```
NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

//Play the movie now
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
[[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];
```

Comment: I am receiving this thread error when using your code: (lldb) and Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xf00000000)

Comment: @user2536879: Check it now

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

or

```
NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: Add NSLog(@"urlstring %@",[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); in your didselectrow method as first line and say what is in console

Comment: can you check out my edit lease and tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: It should be NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"....

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the player as a property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player`.
And I also recommend to rewrite the getter like this:

```
-(MPMoviewPlayerController *)player {
    if(!_player) {
        _player = [[MPMoviewPlayerController alloc] init];
    }
    return _player
}
```

And then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, change the code like this:

```
NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
self.player.contentURL = movieURL;
[[self.player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  
[self.view addSubview: [self.player view]];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: @user2536879 Ah I know what's the problem here. Since `filePathArray` only contains the file name and the extension, so when you wanna get the `movieURL` you should add it to the document directory like this: `NSString *movieURLString = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`